# Maven ant plugin needs to use Ant 1.8

Tags: maven, ant, maven-plugin

I've create a Maven Ant plugin that bundles up a load of Ant macros based upon the guides

http://books.sonatype.com/mcookbook/reference/ch04s04.html
http://books.sonatype.com/mvnref-book/reference/writing-plugins-sect-custom-plugin.html#ex-maven-metadata

I have the plugin working and using Ant contrib though I have a problem that its using

Ant **1.7** instead of **1.8** which mean that my **include** statements are failing

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.openbet.shared:openbet-shared_ant:2.4-SNAPSHOT:options (default-cli) on project openbet-office: Failed to execute: Executing Ant script: ci.build.xml [run]: Failed to parse. Problem: failed to create task or type include
[ERROR] Cause: The name is undefined.
[ERROR] Action: Check the spelling.
[ERROR] Action: Check that any custom tasks/types have been declared.
[ERROR] Action: Check that any <presetdef>/<macrodef> declarations have taken place.
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
```

I've managed to use echoproperties in order to verify its 1.7

```
[echoproperties] java.runtime.name=Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment
[echoproperties] ant.file.ci.plugin=/tmp/plexus-ant-component586072324287432616.build.xml
[echoproperties] sun.boot.library.path=/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun-1.6.0.26/jre/lib/amd64
[echoproperties] java.vm.version=20.1-b02
[echoproperties] ant.version=Apache Ant version 1.7.1 compiled on June 27 2008
[echoproperties] ant.core.lib=/home/jmorgan/.m2/repository/org/apache/ant/ant/1.7.1/ant-1.7.1.jar

[echoproperties] ant.java.version=1.6
[echoproperties] java.vendor.url=http\://java.sun.com/
[echoproperties] java.vm.vendor=Sun Microsystems Inc.
```

The project that uses the plugin also uses the Antrun plugin. This is > Ant 1.8

```
[echoproperties] ant.core.lib=/home/jmorgan/.m2/repository/org/apache/ant/ant/1.8.2/ant-1.8.2.jar
[echoproperties] ant.java.version=1.6
[echoproperties] ant.project.default-target=package
[echoproperties] ant.project.invoked-targets=test
[echoproperties] ant.project.name=maven-antrun-
[echoproperties] ant.version=Apache Ant(TM) version 1.8.2 compiled on December 20 2010
```

If I run ant on the command line I get

```
> ant -v
 Apache Ant version 1.8.0 compiled on April 9 2010
```

All I need to do is to get the plugin using 1.8 and I reckon everything should fall into place

Any help greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Just like you can add dependencies to your project, you can add dependencies to a plugin. Especially nice if you want to use a different version of a plugin dependency like you do. So you don't have to wait for the next release of the plugin.

See http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-configuring-plugins.html#Using_the_dependencies_Tag

Lucky you, it is actually using the maven-antrun-plugin as example

Comment: Excellent. I already have dependencies. For some reason I didn't know I could add Ant as a dependency. Makes sense. Thanks

Comment: That sorted it out. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

Adding **ant** to my dependencies sorted the problem

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>com.xxxxx.shared</groupId>
    <artifactId>xxxxx-shared_ant</artifactId>
    <version>3.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ant-contrib</groupId>
            <artifactId>ant-contrib</artifactId>
            <version>1.0b3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.ant</groupId>
            <artifactId>ant</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.oopsconsultancy</groupId>
            <artifactId>xmltask</artifactId>
            <version>1.16</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```